# Simplifying $\sum_x\frac{(A+2x)!}{(2x)!}$

Tags: summation, factorial

Is there a "simple" form to
\begin{align}
\sum_{x=0}^{x_1}\frac{(A+2x)!}{(2x)!}\, \tag{1}
\end{align}

Mathematica spits out the not very illuminating
\begin{align}
\sum_{x=0}^{x_1}\frac{(A+2x)!}{(2x)!}=2^{-A-2} A!-\frac{\left(A+2 x_1+2\right)! \,
   _3F_2\left(1,\frac{A}{2}+x_1+\frac{3}{2},\frac{A}{2}+x_1+2;x_1+\frac{3}{2},x_1+2;1\right)}{\left(2
   \left(x_1+1\right)\right)!}\, .
\end{align}
Here, $x$, $x_1$ and $A$ are non-negative integers.

I suspect the cases where $A$ is even or odd probably have to be treated differently.  Still according to Mathematica, the simpler expression $$
\sum_{x=0}^{x_0}\frac{(A+x)!}{x!}=\frac{(1+A+x_1)!}{(1+A)x_1!}$$ so one would think that the more complicated one should also eventually give something "simpler".

(Any reference or insight to this type of summation is welcomed.)

Comment: is $x\in \mathbb{N}$? or $\mathbb{Z}$? also, what about $A$?

Comment: @Schach21 I edited to clarify.

Comment: what is the easy expression for $\sum_x \frac{(A+x)!}{x!}$?

Comment: @Schach21 edited to accommodate your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a general answer.

Consider
$$
I = \sum_{k=0}^{2x_1} \begin{pmatrix}A+k \\ k\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
J = \sum_{k=0}^{2x_1} (-1)^k \begin{pmatrix}A+k \\ k\end{pmatrix}
$$
What you look for is obviously $I+J$ (multiplied by $A!/2$) as odd terms cancel out and only even terms remain.

The first one is $I = \begin{pmatrix}A+2x_1 + 1\\ 2x_1\end{pmatrix}$ like you mentioned.

The later one seems trickier. You can maybe refer
[to negative binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series)
where binomial coefficients can be extended to $\begin{pmatrix}p\\ k\end{pmatrix}$ where $p\in\mathbb Z$. The definition is ( $n\in\mathbb N$)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-n \\ k
\end{pmatrix} := (-1)^k
\begin{pmatrix}
n+k-1 \\ k
\end{pmatrix}
$$
With this convention,
$$
J = \sum_{k=0}^{2x_1} (-1)^k \begin{pmatrix}A+k \\ k\end{pmatrix} = \sum_{k=0}^{2x_1} \begin{pmatrix}1-A \\ k\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the latter has no closed forms when $1-A$ is positive, but it doubtfully has one when it is also negative which is your case.

There might be special cases like $A=1$ or $A=0$.

Comment: Interesting idea to write the sum in this way.  Yes for specific values of $A$ like $A=0$ and $A=1$ one can immediately simplify the ratio and obtain a closed form.